# Php class Controller not found

Tags: php

I have main index.php file where i call other controllers and that is fine.

I call them with **call_user_func_array( [ $obj, $method[ 0 ] ], $params );**

For example i first include controller and then i call it. My controller is called HomeController and this is example how i include it and call it.

```
require( 'system/mvc/controller/'. $controller .'.php' );
$obj = new $controller;
call_user_func_array( [ $obj, $method[ 0 ] ], $params );
```

And that is ok and its working.

So my system/mvc/controller/HomeController.php looks like this:

```
<?php

class HomeController
{

    public function test()
    {
        echo 'Something!';
    }

   }

    ?>
```

And this is ok. Now i was tried to include main controller.php file that will extends my HomeController. So in my index.php file i included system/lib/php/Controller.php and code now looks like this in index.php

```
require( 'system/mvc/controller/'. $controller .'.php' );
require( 'system/lib/php/controller.php' );
$obj = new $controller;
call_user_func_array( [ $obj, $method[ 0 ] ], $params );
```

And in HomeController i used **class HomeController extends Controller** and i got this error:
**Fatal error: Class 'Controller' not found in /var/www/html/system/mvc/controller/HomeController.php on line 3**

Tried to use namespaces but that didnt work.

Comment: Try to include your Controller class in HomeController class

Comment: thanks! this is working! but is there another way so i dont have to include main controller  in every single controller?

Comment: Include your, Controller on top of your index.php file

Comment: i suggest you learn about composer, and its autoloading functionality, so you don't need to require files manually. composer has become industry standard over the last 6 years: https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change

> require( 'system/mvc/controller/'. $controller .'.php' ); require(
>   'system/lib/php/controller.php' );

to

> require( 'system/lib/php/controller.php' ); require(
>   'system/mvc/controller/'. $controller .'.php' );

Comment: thanks! now i see where my mistake is. first called homecontroller and then main controller so homecontroller didnt recognized my main controller.

Comment: Yeah you got it :)

Comment: Yes :) that's it